# Group action and Radon measure

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, group-actions

Let $\mathscr M(\mathbb R)$ be the Banach space of complex-valued Radon measures on $\mathbb R$, and let $\pi$ be the action of $\mathbb R$ on $\mathscr M(\mathbb R)$. Let $\mathscr A$ denote a subset of $\mathscr M(\mathbb R)$ such that $\pi_x(\mu)$ is continuous with respect to $x$ for every $\mu \in \mathscr A$.

My question is what does $\mathscr A$ looks like?

Comment: I am not an expert in group theory, but is there a unique $\pi$? Anyways, could you please specify its action explicitly?

Comment: One can show that $\mathscr{A} = L^1(\mathbb R)$. The best proof of this depends on the tools you want to use. @Ilya: There are many actions of $\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathscr{M}(\mathbb{R})$, but the intended one will be the one given by translation $\pi(x,\mu) = \mu(A+x)$.

Comment: @Martin: thanks, that's the one I thought about - just wondered whether there is only one (natural?) choice of the action.

Comment: @Ilya: It seems to be the only interesting one in this context: Maybe one sees clearer when looking at it more abstractly: If a group acts on a set, it naturally acts on all kinds of functions on that set and consequently also on the measures. Now if the set happens to be the group itself there are various natural choices for the action: left/right translation or the conjugations. For an abelian group conjugation is quite uninteresting and the two translation actions coincide, so that's going to be the one... More concisely: the group $G$ acts on its measures $\mathscr{M}(G)$ by push-forward.

Comment: @Martin: nice, that was a useful comment for me